# How to fusion two content elements? / Does an all in one content element exist?

Tags: element, typo3, fusion

I need a content element that cointains apsects from the "Textpic" and the "Media" content elements.
Basically I need the whole palette of input masks of the textpic CE (headline, rte text, images) plus the media tab (swf, mp4, mov) from the media content element.

This special requirements for our project comes from the need that we can only use one content element for our specific javascript content slieder. So I can not use like a Textpic and underneath a media CE. No it really has to be just one CE which can handle the textpic + the media CE stuff.

Generally I ask you: Is there already a extension, trick, modification or a framework which I can/should be use to achive that i can "fusionate" content elements? Like an "all-in-one"-content element, a multi content element?

Ps: I do not use Templavoila. My Typo3 version is 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the tutorial you're looking for:
http://castironcoding.com/resources/our-blog/sp/view/single/post/reason-6-for-choosing-typo3-custom-content-elements-and-extbase-again-part-23.html

Follow step 2 and 3.

You'll also need to add a specific rendering config in Typoscript ie: `tt_content._your-ce_`

But it can be copied from out of `tt_content.textpic` and `tt_content.media`. You can find the expample typoscript of before mentioned CE's in: `typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/setup.txt`. Just don't alter it there, but make a copy and alter in your own file.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to only talk about reusing already exisiting fields, you really only need to change the backend interface (big keyword: "showitem"). You'll need the database names of the fields (peek into the tt_content table of some records where you know the contents), alternatively visit the module Admin Tools / Configuration, select TCA in top dropdown menu, open tt_content and columns.

Try http://blog.chandanweb.com/typo3/adding-new-fields-to-existing-typo3-tables-at-desired-location, you'll of course have to substitue tt_content for tt_news etc.

You might also want to make a new type (the above recipe is for changing a preexisitent), but I'm sorry, I'm currently out of time for explaining that. It's not very hard, though, and the castiron link by Koopa will help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can wrap the content column in another div? You can use that outer div for your content slider.  Now you actually use all content elements seperately, but combine then for usage.